# How to serve complete htmlapp with django server using views.py

Tags: python, django

I have a folder which contains complete frontend built in oraclejet, you can get copy from here (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jet/downloads/index.html) download base distribution to get an idea. Folder contains index.html js and other files.

To serve this file with django I kept all files from this inside
"myapp/template/myapp" folder. contents from folder

```
admin
CONTRIBUTING.md
css
index.html
js
LICENSE.md
metadata
package.json
README.md
revnum
scss
THIRDPARTYLICENSE.txt
```

myproject - contains manage.py

**I want to serve all files using django without using webserver or static mechanism provided by django, as I don't want to modify anything frontend files**

Now, in Flask I simply did this, and it worked no issues.

```
@app.route("/demo/<path:path>", methods=['GET'])
def static_resource(path):
    return send_from_directory('./demo/', path)
```

But how to achieve same thing in Django ?

**urls.py**

urlpatterns
re_path (r'^$', views.index , name='index'),
re_path (r'^(?P.*)$',views.test_files1 , name='name' )

**views.py**

```
def test_files(request , name):
    fname = "/home/archit/django_src/mysite/myapp/templates/myapp/" + name
    fsock = open(fname,"rb")
    return HttpResponse(fsock)
```

I think there should be something simliar to "send_from_directory('./demo/', path)" in django as well

Please Don't suggest answer for with below solutions as answers already available on stackoverflow

1. How to serve web pages with apache server
2. Don't want to change even single line with default oraclejet code, so adding {{ % static }} in html files not solution for me

Comment: Why use Django at all if you're not planning on using any of its features? Why not just dump these files in a directory, and point your web server (either Apache or nginx) to said folder?